# Croppie and NodeJS : Upload resized images

Tags: node.js

I'm trying to upload squared images for my ecommerce app.
I want all my images to be square for products images.

I'm using croppie Js, Expressjs and ejs.

Here is my actual code :

```
                <label>Image</label>
                <div id="modal">
                <a class="button actionUpload">
                        <input class="from-control" type="file" id="upload" value="Choose Image" name="image" accept="image/*">
                    </div>
                </a>
                <div id="main-cropper"></div>
                <button class="actionDone">Done</button>
```

And my JavaScript

```
var basic = $('#main-cropper').croppie({
    viewport: {
        width: 200,
        height: 200
    },
    boundary: {
        width: 300,
        height: 300
    },
    showZoomer: true,
    url: '/images/logo_AR.png'
});
basic.hide()

function readFile(input) {
    if (input.files && input.files[0]) {
        basic.show()
        var reader = new FileReader();

        reader.onload = function (e) {
            $('#main-cropper').croppie('bind', {
                url: e.target.result
            });
            $('.actionDone').toggle();
            $('.actionUpload').toggle();
        }

        reader.readAsDataURL(input.files[0]);
    }
}

$('.actionUpload input').on('change', function () {
    readFile(this);
});
$('.actionDone').on('click', function () {
    $('.actionDone').toggle();
    $('.actionUpload').toggle();
})
```

When I upload the image on AWS using multer on my rooter, the crop doesnt work and the images isn't modified...